# Date parameter not evaluated correctly when using ADO and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 420, DueDate, ISNULL(Amount, 0) 
FROM Payments
WHERE CurveID = ? AND DueDate >= ?;
```

which I am executing using Delphi 2010 and TADODataset. The statement executes correctly except that the evaluation of the clause `DueDate >= ?` is not correct. If I pass in `Date()` or `Now()` for second parameter I get values returned with dates earlier than today in the `DueDate` field.

In SSMS, I can run this SQL query successfully if I replace the date parameter with a string in the format '2011-09-09' like this:

```
SELECT 420, DueDate, ISNULL(Amount, 0) 
FROM Payments
WHERE CurveID = 19 AND DueDate >= '2011-09-09';
```

However, back in Delphi, even if I set my parameter value to a stringified version of the date in this format, I get the incorrect results (presumably because TADODataset is correctly converting the string back into a date).

What must I do, short of building dynamic SQL with the date hard-coded into the SQL to get this to evaluate correctly?

Comment: Is `DueDate` a datetime object in the table?

Comment: Sorry, yes DueDate is of type DATETIME.

Comment: @Larry - are the results off by two days? I assume you mean that `DueDate` is of type `DATETIME` in the database but what is the type of the parameter? Is it a `Float`? Can you save the `TADOQuery.SQL` to a file and verify what get's send to the server?

Comment: I tried passing the results of Date() and Now() (TDate and TDateTime) respectively into the parameter, as well as FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Date()) (type String).

Comment: @Larry - do you create a parameter object? What type is it? What can you tell us about my other questions? *(Are the results off by two days...)*

Comment: No, when I issue that query I get back DueDate values from, for instance, March 2011.  I don't create the parameter object, rather I pass in the SQL to TADODataset and it creates the parameter objects.  I also pass an array of variants and use that to set the parameter values.  I have not yet checked the actual types of the parameters TADODataset is creating for me, I will try that.  If I inspect the value of TADODataset.SQL it does not show me the parameter substitution, I believe that happens on the server anyway, right?

Comment: @Larry - I'm not sure. Should the results be off by two days, the parameter is most likely interpreted as a float and you are experiencing what is described [here](https://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.database.sqlservers/browse_frm/thread/b2e07edb46f63cba/1ab62659d8be3135?lnk=st&q=2+sqlserver+com+datetime+group:&hl=nl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem:

I was using TADOCommand to execute the SQL against the database (not TADODataset as I mistakenly wrote in the question, oops).  Switching to TADOQuery solved the problem.  The execute SQL interface is different between the two classes and TADOQuery unequivocally looks at the Parameters property of the dataset for it's parameters.  TADOCommand has a Parameters property, but also accept an array of Parameter as an argument to the .Execute() method.

With TQuery my parameters are correctly typed without additional effort on my part.  This works with position or named parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Use (named) parameters, something like

```
Query.CommandText := 'SELECT 420, DueDate, ISNULL(Amount, 0) FROM Payments '+
                     'WHERE CurveID = :CurveID AND DueDate >= :DueDate';
Query.Prepared := True;
Query.Parameters.ParamValues['CurveID'] := 19;
Query.Parameters.ParamValues['DueDate'] := EncodeDate(2011, 9, 9);
Query.Active := True;
```

This also allows you to set the type of the parameter should the system not to get it right, ie

```
Query.Parameters.ParamByName('DueDate').DataType := ftDate;
```

Note also that [ParamCheck](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOCommand.ParamCheck) property of the ADODataSet must be `true` (default) in order to use `:name` style parameters.

Comment: Change this to use `ParamByName` and `AsInteger` and `AsDateTime` instead, so that the drivers do the conversions, and I'll upvote it. :)

Comment: @Ken the trouble is, the `TParameter` object returned by `ParamByName` doesn't have `As*` properties, only `Value: Variant`.

Comment: You're right about `AsInteger`, of course. I was thinking of `TDataSet`. Instead: `Param := ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('CurveID');
  Param.DataType := ftInteger;
  Param.Value := 19;
  Param := ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('DueDate');
  Param.DataType := ftDateTime;
  Param.Value := EncodeDateTime(2011, 9, 9);` Ah, I see you got it. :) I think you can still use `ParamValues` and assign the return to `Param` as well. Either way, +1
`

Comment: Seting the data types of the parameters is probably good idea, althought for me the system uses correct type (date) when using named parameters anyway... I guess in that case the metadata is loaded and used before actually substituting the values.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
AND DueDate >= CONVERT(datetime,?);
```

Comment: Thanks, but no apparent effect.  The command still runs, and still returns earlier dates.

Answer (score 0):

Are the regional settings different between the Delphi client and the SQL Server?  This can cause invalid dates to be returned.  Though I admit that if month = year as in "9/9/2011", that should not matter.

We had issues like this using a French Canadian C# client talking to a US-English database server.  The client formatted April 1, 2011 as '1/4/2011' which the database interpreted as January 4, 2011.

Comment: I'm developing on SQL Server Express on my own laptop, so I don't think so.

Comment: @Larry: Access always treat all date literals as if they were formatted as "mm/dd/yyyy", regardless of any regional settings... Don't know about sql server, but as it is from the same MS stable I'd recommend: don't think, check.

Answer (score 0):

Zero date is not same in OS and DB , 01/01/1900 v/s 30/12/1899. You need to +/- 2 days depending on select/update.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've noticed is the difference in behaviour between assigning ParamByName and ParamValues using Delphi TDateTime values

```
var
  MyDate: TDateTime

AdoQuery1.ParamByName('DueDate').AsDateTime := MyDate // works with US English
//vs 
AdoQuery1.ParamValues['DueDate'] := MyDate // works with various date formats
```

There is no differences when your ShortDate Settings are English US, but when they are not, ParamByName does not do the conversion correctly for all settings.

ParamValues does the conversion correctly. I'm guessing that the conversion code for variants is "better" than the conversion between Delphi TDateTime values and ADO DateTime values - which is why I have moved away from using ParamByName in my applications.

Comment: TParameter (The result type of ParamByName) does not have an .AsDateTime property or method.